# Trimming a string before substring

Tags: java

```
/**
 * Shortens input by only having one letter in the output. 
 *If user inputs blank      answer, default is size Small.
 */

if (!burgerSize.isEmpty()) {
    burgerSize = burgerSize.trim().toUpperCase();
    burgerSize = burgerSize.substring(0, 1);
}
```

When I did this in my project, the command line said:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException... String index out of range: 1
>
> at java.lang.String.substring(String.java:1...)
>
> at BurgerOrder.main(BurgerOrder.java:66)"

If I switch the lines around, it doesn't do that...but my teacher told me to trim the string before the substring.

```
if (!burgerSize.isEmpty()) {
    burgerSize = burgerSize.substring(0, 1);
    burgerSize = burgerSize.trim().toUpperCase();

}
```

This is what I had originally and it had no errors. Should I just keep it the way it is and accept the points I lost?

UPDATE: Let me clarify.  If the user inputs the letter S like this `"ssss"`, it will shorten and capitalize to "S". Same thing for M like `"mmmmm"` and so on. I know what I'm doing with my code. I'm just wondering if what my professor suggested was wrong (he was reading my code that I printed out).

Comment: Do you understand what each is doing?

Comment: Uh yes, I added comments in the beginning.

Comment: His question was actually rhetorical. You're getting that error for a very good reason; the string is empty after you trim it. If you read the javadoc for `substring` it tells you: IndexOutOfBoundsException - if the beginIndex is negative, or endIndex is larger than the length of this String object

Comment: If your question is answered, then either mark one of the questions here as accepted, or post your own answer and accept it.  There isn't any need to edit your title to include "solved".

Comment: Sorry I'm new to this site, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The String method `isEmpty()` only checks if the string contains no characters at all, not even a space. For example, if `burgerSize = " "` (note the space between the quotes) then the call to `trim()` will remove that space and your call to `substring(0, 1)` will fail because the string is empty, even though it wasn't empty when you first checked it.

Try moving the `trim()` to be above the if statement, like this:

```
burgerSize = burgerSize.trim();
if (!burgerSize.isEmpty())
{
    burgerSize = burgerSize.substring(0, 1).toUpperCase();
}
```

Comment: Thank you! My teacher put his arrow inside the if statement when he was correcting mine.

Answer (score 0):

trim removes whitespace such as spaces.  When burgerSize starts with a space, it's not empty at that point, so it passes the not isEmpty test.  But then when you trim out the space, burgerSize becomes empty, so trying to take the first letter fails.  Try trimming first, then checking for not empty.

Good luck!

Comment: Thank you! My teachers' correction where he put his arrow was in the if statement which confused me. Makes more sense now.

Answer (score 0):

To be safe, you should trim the string before doing the substring. Consider:

```
/**
   <P>{@code java TrimBeforeSubstrXmpl}</P>
 **/
public class TrimBeforeSubstrXmpl  {
   public static final void main(String[] igno_red)  {
      test("sssssssss");
      test("   sssssssss");
   }
   private static final void test(String s_s)  {
      System.out.println("Testing \"" + s_s + "\"");

      s_s = s_s.substring(0, 1);

      System.out.println("   Substring: \"" + s_s + "\"");

      s_s = s_s.trim().toUpperCase();

      System.out.println("   Trimmed then uppercase: \"" + s_s + "\"");
   }
}
```

Output:

```
[C:\java_code\]java TrimBeforeSubstrXmpl
Testing "sssssssss"
   Substring: "s"
   Trimmed then uppercase: "S"
Testing "   sssssssss"
   Substring: " "
   Trimmed then uppercase: ""
```